# Isn't there a Firefox extension hiding `Send link...` from `File` and right-click menu?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

`Send link...` presence annoys me a lot as I never mean to use it but am frequently to click it accidentally (aiming to click `Save link as...`), which initiates an email client (which I use neither) to start coming up with account set-up dialogue. I tend to believe that I am not the only one annoyed with this and so there could be a lightweight extension to remove the annoyance. Isn't there?

Comment: Being open-source, you can modify Firefox code and recompile it.

Comment: As a workaround, you can change the `mailto` program used by firefox (see [mozilla website](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Changing%20the%20e-mail%20program%20used%20by%20Firefox)). Thus, it won't open an external app anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Menu Editor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/menu-editor/?src=search), lets you customize the context menu any way you want.

Comment: Too fast for me... let me just add a link to [this tuto](http://maketecheasier.com/edit-context-menu-in-firefox/2010/09/04)